# Circular dependency between struct and function in C

Tags: c, struct, c99, circular-dependency

I have the following files:

A.h

```
#ifndef __A_H_
#define __A_H_

#include <B.h> // contains foo_t
typedef struct {
     foo_t foo;
     ...
} baz_t;

#endif
```

B.h

```
#ifndef __B_H_
#define __B_H_

#include <A.h> // contains baz_t
typedef struct {
     ...
} foo_t;

extern int useful_func(baz_t d);

#endif
```

When I compile this B.h refuses to compile complaining `error: unknown type name 'baz_t'`

I am assuming this error is owing to circular dependency between the two files. But I am wondering how do I forward declare `baz_t` to solve this? I found answers relating to circular dependencies between structs. But I am unsure how I would solve this. I would appreciate some help here. I am looking for a strictly C99 solution.

EDIT

1. I previously forgot to mention this but I have already used include guards.
2. A very obvious solution as suggested by user KamilCuk is moving `useful_func` to `A.h`. This has also occured to me but software organization wise `useful_func` unfortunately belongs to `B.h`. This problem could be a reflection of a poor design as well.

Comment: Move `extern int useful_func(baz_t d);` to `A.h` and remove `#include <A.h>` from `B.h` - problem solved.

Comment: 1) I hope you're using [#include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).  2) You don't need the "extern" qualifier; the prototype `int useful_func(baz_t d);` should suffice.  3) [System headers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_header_files.htm) use the `#include<some_standard_header.h>` syntax.  You probably want double-quotes - `#include "xyz.h"`.

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk you are absolutely right, but I added an EDIT section now mentioning why I did not take that approach.

Comment: Make a new header, `"useful_func.h"` that contains the extern for `useful_func` (and includes the necessary headers). This would then also allow for "B.h" to not include "A.h" anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You can use forward declaration as follows:

```
struct foo;

typedef struct {
    struct foo foo;
    ...
} baz_t;
```

And then use it normally on B.h

That said, circular dependencies can be avoided is you define everything on a third header that you use as interface. It would be cleaner, but it's not always possible.

Comment: This would work if the `struct` contained a pointer to `foo`. But the forward declaration isn't enough to use a `foo` itself as a member or parameter type, or anything else which  needs the size and contents of a `foo`.

Answer (score -1):

Typically, one would pass pointers to structures rather than passing them by value.  If that would be acceptable, things are easy, since C compilers will accept a declaration:

```
void doSomethingWithAFoo(struct foo *it);
```

without regard for whether they have seen any definition for `struct foo`.  Indeed, compilers will even accept function *definitions* like:

```
void doSomethingWithAFooTwice(struct foo *it)
{
  doSomethingWithAFoo(it);
  doSomethingWithAFoo(it);
}
```

without having to know or care about whether, where, or how `struct foo` is defined.

Note that an advantage of using `struct tag` syntax rather than typedef names is that prototypes using the struct tag syntax don't require declaring or defining anything that can't be harmlessly redeclared arbitrarily many times.